# Long to wide format using variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr, melt

I have a wide dataset that looks like this:

```
dataset <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                      basketball.time1 = c(2, 5, 4, 3, 3),
                      basketball.time2 = c(3, 4, 5, 3, 2),
                      basketball.time3 = c(1, 8, 4, 3, 1),
                      volleyball.time1 = c(2, 3, 4, 0, 1),
                      volleyball.time2 = c(3, 4, 3, 1, 3),
                      volleyball.time3 = c(1, 8, 12, 2, 3))
```

What I want is the dataset in long format, with `id`, `time`, `basketball`, and `volleyball` as separate variables. I want to create the `time` column with three factors (time1, time2, and time3) using the string that is separated by "." at the end of the basketball and volleyball columns.

Thanks so much!

EDIT: fixed typo

Comment: Please share how your expected output would look like.

Comment: You have a misspelling in the last column "vollyeball.time3" that's throwing off people's results

Comment: I think there's a typo in the question `'volleyball' != 'vollyeball'`

Comment: Thanks yes there is a typo, sorry

Comment: FYI each of the posts I marked up top includes a one-line answer with `tidyr::pivot_longer` using the `".value"` special keyword

Comment: Thanks, @camille. Please let us know the reason for the serial downvote to all answers (in case it is yours). Is it because we missed the .values answer or because we answered instead of voting for closure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GuedesBF that wasn't me, although whether or not to downvote answers to questions that have been asked repeatedly is [an ongoing debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253735/5325862)

Comment: Ok, thank you, @camille. The .value advice is excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use`pivor_longer %>% pivot_wider`. `separate`is not needed if we set the appropriate parameters to `pivor_longer`.

```
library(tidyr)

dataset %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = matches('time\\d+$'), names_to = c('sport', 'time'), names_pattern = '(.*)\\.(.*)') %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = sport, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 15 × 5
      id time  basketball volleyball vollyeball
   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1 time1          2          2         NA
 2     1 time2          3          3         NA
 3     1 time3          1         NA          1
 4     2 time1          5          3         NA
 5     2 time2          4          4         NA
 6     2 time3          8         NA          8
 7     3 time1          4          4         NA
 8     3 time2          5          3         NA
 9     3 time3          4         NA         12
10     4 time1          3          0         NA
11     4 time2          3          1         NA
12     4 time3          3         NA          2
13     5 time1          3          1         NA
14     5 time2          2          3         NA
15     5 time3          1         NA          3
```

Comment: All other solutions below were great but this solution worked perfectly

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                      basketball.time1 = c(2, 5, 4, 3, 3),
                      basketball.time2 = c(3, 4, 5, 3, 2),
                      basketball.time3 = c(1, 8, 4, 3, 1),
                      volleyball.time1 = c(2, 3, 4, 0, 1),
                      volleyball.time2 = c(3, 4, 3, 1, 3),
                      vollyeball.time3 = c(1, 8, 12, 2, 3))

dataset %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  separate(name,into = c("name", "time")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, name, time))

#> # A tibble: 15 × 5
#>       id time  basketball volleyball vollyeball
#>    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1 time1          2          2         NA
#>  2     1 time2          3          3         NA
#>  3     1 time3          1         NA          1
#>  4     2 time1          5          3         NA
#>  5     2 time2          4          4         NA
#>  6     2 time3          8         NA          8
#>  7     3 time1          4          4         NA
#>  8     3 time2          5          3         NA
#>  9     3 time3          4         NA         12
#> 10     4 time1          3          0         NA
#> 11     4 time2          3          1         NA
#> 12     4 time3          3         NA          2
#> 13     5 time1          3          1         NA
#> 14     5 time2          2          3         NA
#> 15     5 time3          1         NA          3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `pivot_longer`
2. `separate` in `sport` and `time` column
3. `pivot_wider` `sport` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -id
  ) %>% 
  separate(name, c("sport", "time")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = sport
  )
```

```
      id time  basketball volleyball vollyeball
   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1 time1          2          2         NA
 2     1 time2          3          3         NA
 3     1 time3          1         NA          1
 4     2 time1          5          3         NA
 5     2 time2          4          4         NA
 6     2 time3          8         NA          8
 7     3 time1          4          4         NA
 8     3 time2          5          3         NA
 9     3 time3          4         NA         12
10     4 time1          3          0         NA
11     4 time2          3          1         NA
12     4 time3          3         NA          2
13     5 time1          3          1         NA
14     5 time2          2          3         NA
15     5 time3          1         NA          3
```